# How to use graphql-js to call APIs from the client code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, graphql-js

I am developing an internal TypeScript library which needs to call a couple of GraphQL endpoints. The library is supposed be imported in front end projects, but it is not dependent on any specific framework (like angular or react).

I would like to be able to use a GraphQL library for GraphQL calls. I checked Apollo, but it brings react with it (which I don't need). In [the graphql-js documentation](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js#using-in-a-browser), it states that it can be used in browser, at the same time they only provide code samples for server-side code.

So far, I am just making plain rest class, but I am interested in generating at least types automatically as it is inconvenient.

**Q:** How to use graphql-js in the client code? Or is there any other way to call graphql endpoints without having to import Apollo with react?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Apollo client does *not* require react. The Apollo client documentation is very react-centric (for Javascript at least) but the client exposes an [API](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/) which can be used without React. Even when building in react it can be useful to use, for example, [client.query()](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.query) to perform a query outside a component context.

See also https://www.brianperry.dev/til/2021/using-apollo-without-react/ for how to import Apollo Client without react:

```
import { ApolloClient, gql, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/core";
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I am missing something, but after adding `@apollo/client` to a fresh npm project, the word `react` occurs 22 times in its `package-lock.json`

Comment: Right, but you don't have to use react at all. Just use the client directly.

Comment: Unfortunately it still requires adding React (fails if I don't do so).

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL requests can be made over HTTP. Most servers follow the ["GraphQL over HTTP" specification](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-over-http). How a request can be done using the `POST` HTTP method can be found in the [documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) and quite a lengthy tutorial [here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/21/send-graphql-queries-with-the-fetch-api-without-using-apollo-urql-or-other-graphql-clients/). Here is a simple fetch example:

```
await fetch('http://your.server.com/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: "...",
    variables: { "a": "..." },
  }),
});
```

For a much better experience and less boilerplate you could use [graphql-request](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request).

```
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request'

const query = gql`
  {
    ...
  }
`

await request('https://api.spacex.land/graphql/', query)
```

I also like to pair the library with [GraphQL Code Generator](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen). You can either create a [fully typed SDK](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-graphql-request) or use the simpler [typed document node](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typed-document-node) to get typesafe query variables and results.

For inspiration on the setup, you could use my [repository](https://github.com/leasy-dev/leasy-sdk-js). It is a bit old and needs some package upgrades, but I think the principles should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is **exactly** what you're after

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request

This is a link to their dependency list. It has no react dependency.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request?activeTab=dependencies

Plus, it's also lightweight and has typescript support (should you need one).

Comment: Just as an aside, it also works pretty well with [GraphQL Code Generator](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-graphql-request)